# problems integrating bootstrap and django

Tags: python, django

i am trying to integrate Bootstrap with Django by copying and pasting the folders from Bootstrap to static folder. But I'm not able to get access to the Bootstrap.css file. It shows 404 error. I did everything as documentation says , but no luck . i am using django 2.x , but I also tried /static , and <% static %>.

```
.
├── blackowl
│   ├── blackowl
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── migrations
│   │   │   └── __init__.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   │   └── views.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   └── wsgi.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── index.html
├── manage.py
├── static
│   ├── bootstrap
│   │   ├── css
│   │   │   └── bootstrap.min.css
│   │   └── js
│   │       └── bootstrap.min.js
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── Login-Form-Dark.css
│   │   └── styles.css
│   ├── fonts
│   │   ├── ionicons.eot
│   │   ├── ionicons.min.css
│   │   ├── ionicons.svg
│   │   ├── ionicons.ttf
│   │   └── ionicons.woff
│   ├── img
│   │   └── star-sky.jpg
│   └── js
│       └── jquery.min.js
└── templates
    └── index.html
```

settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

index.html

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
    {% load static %}
header
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/fonts/ionicons.min.css' %}">
```

images

```
background: #475d62 url("{% static 'img/star-sky.jpg' %}");
```

Comment: try adding this to settings.py `STATICFILES_DIRS = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')`

Comment: it works , but the image isnt showing

Comment: is that in some css file or inside `style` tag in some html file?

Comment: it is inside css

Comment: it will not work then. You can use `{% static ... %}` in django templates only, ie. html files inside templates folder. It will not work in .css or .js files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your static files must be located at you app level directory in development mode.
Django will look inside respective app directory while serving static files in development mode

In your case move static directory to to `blackowl/blackowl`.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'fonts/ionicons.min.css' %}">
```

to serve static files from css located at `css/styles.css`:

Use relative path to static files.

```
 background: #000 url(../img/star.png);
```

> Store your static files in a folder called static in your app. For example my_app/static/my_app/example.jpg.

Documentation covered here [managing static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/)

Comment: I did that , but my css file contains a  ```background: #475d62 url("{% static 'img/star-sky.jpg' %}");``` how can I {% static ?%}